# RDS Postgres to Kinesis Data stream for real time load of data through AWS glue

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-kinesis

The requirement is to load data from RDS POSTGRES to RDS oracle on a real-time basis.

AWS Glue is the ETL tool. AWS Glue has a feature to take data from Kinesis in real-time for streaming.

I am struggling to bring data to Kinesis from Postgres.

Any suggestions??

Answer (score 1):

I used this link to push data into kinesis--

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/stream-changes-from-amazon-rds-for-postgresql-using-amazon-kinesis-data-streams-and-aws-lambda/

points to be noted-

- used Ec2.
- No need to explicitly install wal2JSON , it is already there.
- it produces data in a certain JSON structure. Change it to the structure as required(target database)
- I used glue 2.0.

Feel free to post here if any one face any issue. Will try to answer.